# What is the Shulchan Aruch Ha'Arizal?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, authorship, arizal

What is the Shulchan Aruch Ha'Arizal? I expect it to be a compilation of Rabbi Yitzchak Luria's teachings on halacha arranged according to the order of Rabbi Yosef Karo's Shulchan Aruch, or perhaps a Hasidic composition, similar to the Shulchan Aruch HaRav.

Who authored it?

Comment: It is not a book of halakha, and is not related to the Shulhan Arukh. It is a book of minhagim (customs) of a kabbalistic nature. I think the customs were picked out from the writings of Hayyim Vital.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was composed by the students of the Ari z"l outlining how the Ari performed the mitzvot. Here is a link that you can look at: [Shulchan Aruch HaAri z'l](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20908&st=&pgnum=1).

Comment: +1 I seem to remember his son in law was involved or at least quoted regarding certain practices. For instance his wearing his talis katan directly on his bare skin, something some people nowadays think is not allowed.